# Proof of simple conditional logic with resolution

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I have a problem where there are two traffic lights in a junction. If the red light $R_i$ in traffic light $i=1,2$ is on, then green either $R$ or yellow $Y$ is on the other light and vice versa. I think this can be expressed as

$$(R_1 \leftrightarrow (G_2 \lor Y_2)) \land (R_2 \leftrightarrow(G_1 \lor Y_1))$$

Also we need to enforce that two lights cannot be on simultaneously and one light exactly is on at each time,

\begin{align}\neg (G_i \land Y_i)\land \neg(G_i \land R_i) \land \neg (Y_i \land R_i)\land(G_i\lor Y_i \lor R_i)\end{align}

How would one proof with resolution that two red lights cannot be on simultaneously?

Obviously if $R_i=1$, then either $G_{i^\prime}$ or $Y_{i^\prime}$ is 1 ($i^\prime = 1$ if $i = 2$ and vice versa) because otherwise $R_i \leftrightarrow (G_{i^\prime} \lor Y_{i^\prime}) =0$. Thus because $G_{i^\prime}$ or $Y_{i^\prime}$ is 1, $R_{i^\prime}$ cannot be 1 simultaneously because we would violate the clauses that exactly one light is on (To be more specific either $\neg(G_i \land R_i) \land \neg (Y_i \lor R_i)=0$). It seems clear cut, but I cannot formulate the formal resolution proof. Any help?

Comment: You should add parenthesis in your first formula, like so: $(R_1 \leftrightarrow (G_1 \lor Y_1)) \land (R_2 \leftrightarrow(G_2 \lor Y_2))$. However, you mixed the indices somewhere. As for your second question, you can always explore all the possibilities in a table, and show that your formula is true iff the conditions you stated are respected.

Comment: @Mariuslp good catch I edited my question. Yes it is clear from the truth table that two red's cannot be on simultaneously but I would like to know how the resolution method can be applied to yield the same conclusion.

Comment: You need to clausify everything first when doing resolution.  I suggest that you do that first.  If you don't know, this fairly short video explains the INDO method of clasuification/conversion to clausal form: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjKA-sbwh_M&list=PLn4qH88IZbYnW5jbzYYXCBDrghSJf06DN&index=19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to write down all the [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) corresponding to the premises, with the *negation* of the [sought conclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)#A_resolution_technique).

If the conclusion is "that two red lights cannot be on simultaneously", we can formalize it as :

> $\lnot (R_1 \land R_2)$.

There are four clauses produced from the second premise:

1) $¬G_1 ∨ ¬Y_1$

2) $¬G_1 ∨ ¬ R_1$

3) $¬Y_1 ∨ ¬R_1$

4) $G_1 ∨ Y_1 ∨ R_1$

and the same : 5)-8) for $i=2$.

From the other premise we have : $R_1 \to (G_2 ∨ Y_2)$ i.e.

9) $¬R_1 ∨ G_2 ∨ Y_2$

and : $¬(G_2 ∨ Y_2) ∨ R_1$ i.e.

10) $¬G_2 ∨ R_1$

11) $¬Y_2 ∨ R_1$

and the same : 12)-14) for $i=2$.

Finally, we have to add the negation of the conclusion:

15) $R_1$

16) $R_2$.

Finally, we apply the resolution procedure.

Answer (score 1):

While @MauroALLEGRANZA has given the systematic solution, let me show a shortcut I'd use if I were to solve this problem with paper and pencil.  These three clauses, which are part of your assumptions,

$$(\neg G_i \vee \neg R_i) \wedge (\neg Y_i \vee \neg R_i) \wedge (G_i \vee Y_i \vee R_i)$$

are easily verified to be the CNF equivalent of $(G_i \vee Y_i) \leftrightarrow (\neg R_i)$.  By transitivity of equivalence you are done:

$$ R_i \leftrightarrow (G_{3-i} \vee Y_{3-i}) \leftrightarrow (\neg R_{3-i}) ~~~\text{ for } i \in \{1,2\} \enspace.$$

As an aside, real traffic lights may have simultaneous red lights for both intersecting roads, because the actual safety requirement they have to satisfy is the weaker

$$ (G_{3-i} \vee Y_{3-i}) \rightarrow R_i ~~~\text{ for } i \in \{1,2\} \enspace. $$